# XMLSocket exceptions

Tags: apache-flex

I am trying to send some data from XMLSocket in flex script to TCP server socket on localhost, port 12345
 :

```
        import flash.net.XMLSocket;
        import flash.system.System;
        private var socket:XMLSocket;
        private function xmlConnectHandler( event:Event ):void {
             txtInfo.text += "xmlConnectHandler";
            socket.send( "<test>Connection from flex<test/>" );  
        }
        private function XmlConnect():void
        {
            socket = new flash.net.XMLSocket();
            socket.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, xmlConnectHandler);
            socket.connect(null, 12345);

        }
]]>
</fx:Script>

<mx:VBox>
<s:Label id="lblStatus"/>
<mx:Button label="Test" click="XmlConnect()" />
<mx:TextInput id="txtInfo" />
</mx:VBox>
```

I have

> Error #2044: Unhandled ioError:. text=Error #2031: Socket Error.  at
>   Main/XmlConnect()     at Main/___Main_Button1_click()
>
> Error #2044: Unhandled securityError:. text=Error #2048: Security
>   sandbox violation: file:///C:/flex/src/Main.swf cannot load data from
>   :12345.   at Main/XmlConnect()    at Main/___Main_Button1_click()

Is this a security problem? This is confusing: I thought I am trying to connect to "local domain" in the case of localhost connection with "socket.connect(null, 12345)", do i still need a policy file anyway?
Thank you,
-V

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read up on [XMLSocket Policy Files](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000471.html).

Comment: I tried to add Security.loadPolicyFile("file:///C:\policy.xml") where "policy.xml" permitted all access: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd> 
<!-- Policy file for xmlsocket://socks.mysite.com --> 
<cross-domain-policy>  
    <allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*" />
</cross-domain-policy>
Does not seem to make any difference

Comment: I don't think you can point to a local file like that.  It has to be 'served' out somehow (normally through the xmlsocket server, on port 843) or else it'll be useless the second you put it up online.

Comment: How's the security file suppose to be "served"? I tried to send it to the same socket connection from my XML server socket - no progress.

Comment: Is there any place that explains normal solution for this problem, instead of providing heap of useless documentation.

Comment: Some do it over the xmlsocket, some do it over a web server.  Either way, it needs to be available online.  I believe there's also a domain issue (needs to be under the same domain as your swf files).  These are all pretty much standard security features of Flash. Also, you might want to use wildcards (*) in your policy file instead of just leaving them blank.

Comment: from documentation: The XML socket server might be configured to serve policy files in the following ways:
    To serve policy files and normal socket connections over the same port. The server should wait for <policy-file-request /> before transmitting a policy file. I added the code to my XMLServer, sending policy string back. Doesn't seem to make any difference.